# How can I solve this integral?

Tags: probability, statistics, integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution

How can I solve the following integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^n \bigg( 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{c - \mu_i}{\sigma_i}\right) \bigg) \frac{1}{\sigma_Y}\phi \bigg(\frac{c-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} \bigg)
\,\mathrm dc$$

where Φ(⋅) is the CDF of Normal distribution and ϕ(⋅) is the pdf of Normal distribution.

even when $n=1$ I cannot solve it. I would appreciate if you could help me either for the case that $n=1$ or the above general case.

Comment: I know this is from statistics, but  you may want to define your terms for the nonspecialists who still may be able to help you.

Comment: IF $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of Normal RV and $\phi(\cdot)$ is the pdf of Normal RV, did you try $\frac{1}{\sigma} \phi \bigg( \frac{c-\mu}{\sigma} \bigg)dc=d \Phi \bigg(\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma} \bigg)$

Comment: thank you I edited the question

Comment: No I did not try this. How can this substitution solve this integral?

Comment: Got something from my answer below?

Comment: for n>1 , I still dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Considering independent random variables $X_i$ and $Y$, gaussian with mean and variance $(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ and $(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$ respectively, this integral is
$$
\mathbb P(\min\limits_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i\geqslant Y).
$$
If $n=1$, its value is
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{\mu_1-\mu_Y}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_Y^2}}\right).
$$
For $n\geqslant2$, I see no reason to expect some simple explicit formulas in the general case.

Comment: I also found List of integrals of Gaussian functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions  but this list does not help